# How to gradually speed up a game overtime

Tags: javascript, html

```
for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
  myObstacles[i].x += -10;
  myObstacles[i].update();
  if (myGameArea.frameNo >= 100 >= everyinterval(100)) {
    myObstacles[i].x += -5
    myObstacles[i].update();
  }
}

function everyinterval(n) {
  if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

in this case "myGameArea.frameNo" is the score of the game, and "myObstacles" is the speed of the obstacles. What I would like to do is every time it reaches another 100 score it adds -5 speed to the obstacles. So at 0-99 the speed would be -10, at 100-199 the speed would be -15 and so on. I'm confused so thank you for your time and help

I could do this instead

```
  if (myGameArea.frameNo >= 100) {
    myObstacles[i].x += -5
    myObstacles[i].update();
  }
  if (myGameArea.frameNo >= 200) {
    myObstacles[i].x += -5
    myObstacles[i].update();
  }
  if (myGameArea.frameNo >= 300) {
    myObstacles[i].x += -5
    myObstacles[i].update();
  }
```

what I want is a faster way of doing each line

Comment: `every time it reaches another 100 score`, what do you mean *another 100 score*? how can it be "another"? the scores goes beyond 100? you mean you want to count when it reaches 100 then 200 then 300...?

Comment: as it is so far, the score goes on forever until the game ends.  So when it reaches 100 the speed goes up, 200 it goes up again and 300 it goes up again, and so on until the game ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this instead of using if

speed +=-5*(1+ score/100);

example:

so
when score is <100

-5*(1+99/100)=-5*(1+0)=-5

when score is say 103

-5*(1+103/100)=-5*(1+1)=-10

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```js
var start_speed = 5,      // default speed
    speed = start_speed; 

// constantly re-calculate the sceed accodring to the score, on every frame:

speed = start_speed + Math.floor(score/100) * 5;

// on score below '100' speed will be 5 + 0
// on score '100' speed will be 5 + 5
// on score '200' speed will be 5 + 10
```

You can tinker with the math to output the desired speed update

Comment: would I use speed instead of 100 in "myGameArea.frameNo >= 100"?

Comment: what does `frameNo` represent if not a **frame number**? why would it represent "score"?

Comment: It does represent frame number, just in this case it also is the score, as the score goes up quickly. just do you mind putting the "speed" variable into a full if statement, i am a little confused on where I would put it

Comment: What controls the `speed` currently? obviously you cannot and should not modify the `frameNo` variable since it should always points to the the right frame number.. then it seems like you are missing some variable which controls the speed itself. You need to set it up somewhere

Comment: "myObstacles[i].x" is what i use to control the speed, by making it increase, the speed of my obstacles increase.  The score is just me displaying the frame number at the side of the screen, and when the frame number hits 100, i would like it to increase "myObstacles[i].x"

Comment: You can use the formula I suggest to change the `myObstacles[i].x` value, you don't really need `speed` variable. but you should probably have some sort of `start_speed` variable

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good example of a case where you would use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). You can implement the requested behaviour as follows:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; ++i) {
    if (myGameArea.frameNo[i] % 100 == 0) {
        myObstacles[i].x += 5;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
}
```